# How to Set Base Y-Axis Value and Adjust Label Increments in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, visualization, axis

I am working on a data visualization project using Matplotlib in Python. My dataset, stored in a file named 'data', consists of several metrics categorized by different values. The data structure is as follows:

```
 Metric_A      Metric_B         Metric_C        Metric_D            Category        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        5678            6248427050.0          760180.0            814780.0               1          
        5678            7830964690.0         1002000.0            791890.0               4          
        5678            8134164940.0         1863440.0            806560.0               16         
        5678            8241868510.0         5450460.0            789970.0               64         
        5678            8218447570.0        307575220.0           785940.0              4096        
        5678            8223142270.0        2458953130.0          791590.0             32768        
       11356           10623353330.0          773690.0            826990.0               1          
       11356           13732519690.0         1020190.0            806550.0               4          
       11356           14384837930.0         1910420.0            814120.0               16         
       11356           14556138290.0         5468690.0            806850.0               64         
       11356           14580493160.0        307895860.0           804260.0              4096        
       11356           14554063410.0        2457216490.0          808190.0             32768        
       22713           19361456230.0          783120.0            841000.0               1          
       22713           25560941520.0         1029720.0            818390.0               4          
       22713           26825572840.0         1946920.0            826310.0               16         
       22713           27303161600.0         5549290.0            827340.0               64         
       22713           27264612180.0        307446400.0           818080.0              4096        
       22713           27215405020.0        2459090980.0          822370.0             32768        
       45426           36755561200.0          799010.0            853380.0               1          
       45426           49244196160.0         1039690.0            835790.0               4          
       45426           51953533130.0         1971070.0            841060.0               16         
       45426           52500731970.0         5584340.0            844450.0               64         
       45426           52462674670.0        307732090.0           835060.0              4096        
       45426           52604979360.0        2459386640.0          841320.0             32768        
       90852           71430713310.0          829260.0            874950.0               1          
       90852           96217115180.0         1050310.0            855870.0               4          
       90852           102028192260.0        1976900.0            862490.0               16         
       90852           103067447690.0        5609480.0            862970.0               64         
       90852           103230866950.0       307670180.0           857250.0              4096        
       90852           103142518010.0       2455697910.0          865330.0             32768        
       181704          141121030160.0         869510.0            906860.0               1          
       181704          190675802540.0        1069420.0            889880.0               4          
       181704          201760811530.0        1987680.0            900100.0               16         
       181704          204155816750.0        5594490.0            893770.0               64         
       181704          204666130510.0       307069070.0           890840.0              4096        
       181704          204642693750.0       2460641570.0          893060.0             32768        
       363408          280591251910.0         907250.0            946580.0               1          
       363408          381504627300.0        1102630.0            922780.0               4          
       363408          402071095740.0        1996900.0            928300.0               16         
       363408          406529860930.0        5597340.0            927810.0               64         
       363408          408285051800.0       308367460.0           920860.0              4096        
       363408          407873001590.0       2467019600.0          924760.0             32768        
       726817          559954374550.0         930920.0            968570.0               1          
       726817          759982140480.0        1148950.0            955970.0               4          
       726817          801544664600.0        2011450.0            958380.0               16         
       726817          811462599330.0        5621060.0            955140.0               64         
       726817          813584912070.0       308629960.0           950760.0              4096        
       726817          810909999860.0       2442059510.0          950470.0             32768
```

I have created graphs for each metric (Metric_B, Metric_C, Metric_D) against Metric_A, separated by Category values. Here's a snippet of my code:

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import math

def custom_formatter(Y0, base_power):
    def formatter(x, pos):
        increment = x + Y0
        if increment == Y0:
            return f'$Y_0 = {int(Y0 / 10**base_power)} \\times 10^{base_power}$'
        else:
            return f'$Y_0 + {int(increment / 10**base_power)} \\times 10^{base_power}$'
    return formatter


def plot_graph(data_series, metric_a, categories, graph_title, file_suffix):
    unique_categories = np.unique(categories)
    for category in unique_categories:
        mask = categories == category
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
        filtered_metric_a = metric_a[mask]
        filtered_data_series = data_series[mask]

        Y0 = math.floor(min(filtered_data_series) / 10**math.floor(math.log10(min(filtered_data_series)))) * 10**math.floor(math.log10(min(filtered_data_series)))
        base_power = math.floor(math.log10(Y0))
        adjusted_data_series = filtered_data_series - Y0

        plt.plot(filtered_metric_a, filtered_data_series, marker='o', label=f'Category {category}')

        plt.xlabel('Metric_A')
        plt.ylabel('Metric_B')
        plt.title(graph_title)
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid(True)

        max_adjusted_value = max(adjusted_data_series)
        tick_increment = 10 ** (base_power - 1)
        num_ticks = int(max_adjusted_value / tick_increment) + 2  # +2 for Y0 and one extra tick
        tick_values = np.array([i * tick_increment for i in range(num_ticks)])
        plt.yticks(tick_values, [custom_formatter(Y0, base_power)(tick, None) for tick in tick_values])

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.savefig(f'output2/{file_suffix}_{category}.png')
        plt.close()
def main():
    file_name = 'data.txt'  

    # Assuming the structure of the anonymized file is similar to the original, adjust column indexes if needed
    data = np.loadtxt('output2/' + file_name, skiprows=2)

    metric_a = data[:, 0]  
    metric_b = data[:, 1]  
    metric_c = data[:, 2] 
    metric_d = data[:, 3] 
    category = data[:, 4] 

    plot_graph(metric_b, metric_a, category, 'Metric B vs. Metric A', 'metric_b')
    plot_graph(metric_c, metric_a, category, 'Metric C vs. Metric A', 'metric_c')
    plot_graph(metric_d, metric_a, category, 'Metric D vs. Metric A', 'metric_d')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code generates graphs, but I am facing issues with the formatting of the y-axis:

1. **Excessive Y-Axis Labels for Metric_B:** The graph for Metric_B is generating too many y-axis labels, which makes the graph cluttered and hard to read.
   [image]
2. **Repeated Y-Axis Increments:** The y-axis often shows repeated increments (e.g., Y0, Y0 + increment, Y0 + increment), with identical increment values, which seems incorrect.
   [image]
   **Goal:**

- I want to set the base value (Y0) on the y-axis at 0, where Y0 is a 3-digit number followed by a power of 10 notation.
- Subsequent y-axis values should be increments of Y0, formatted as Y0 + [increment], with each increment being 2 or 3 digits multiplied by a power of 10.

**Specific Questions:**

1. How can I adjust my code to correct the issue of excessive Y-axis labels for Metric_B?
2. What changes are necessary to ensure distinct and correctly formatted y-axis increments?